# Group by and count after cross join in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a trouble with LINQ statement. Which is, i want to "In the X department, Y people are at the level of Z" report or "In the R&D department, 12 people are at the level of 2".

Department Table : id, code, name

DepartmentLevel Table : level

PersonnelDepartment : personnel_id,department_id,currentLevel

Here my LINQ query:

```
var query = (
            from a in cx.Department
            from al in cx.DepartmenLevel
            join pd in cx.PersonnelDepartment on
                new { dId = a.Id, al.Level, IsDeleted = false } equals
                new { dId = ppa.PdAbilityId, Level = pd.CurrentLevel, pd.IsDeleted } into pdj
            from pd in pdj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where a.IsDeleted == false && al.IsDeleted == false
            select new
            {
                dep = new
                {
                    a.Id,
                    a.Code,
                    a.Name
                },
                depLevel = new
                {
                    al.Level
                },
                perDep = new
                {
                    Id = (Guid?)ppa.PdPersonnelId ?? null
                }
            });
```

And mapping in the backend:

```
var tempRes2 = await query.ToListAsync();

        var tempRes = tempRes2
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.dep, g.depLevel, g.perDep })
                    .Select(s => new { s.Key.dep, s.Key.depLevel, s.Key.perDep })
                    .ToList();
        IList<ParentResultDto> result =
        tempRes.GroupBy(g => g.dep).Select(s => new ParentResultDto()
        {
            DepartmentCode = s.Key.Code,
            DepartmentName = s.Key.Name,
            DepartmentLevel = tempRes
                                  .Where(w => w.dep.Id == s.Key.Id)
                                  .GroupBy(g1 => new { g1.depLevel , g1.perDep })
                                  .Select(s1 => new ChildResultDto()
                                  {
                                      Level = s1.Key.depLevel.Level,
                                      PersonnelCount = s1.Key.perDep.Distinct().Count
                                  }).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        return result;
```

Query ise blow up the group by g1.perDep. And i have no idea how to solve this. I think this must be work. Thanks for your reply

Comment: How does it "blow up" exactly?

Comment: I get the "Nullable object must have a value" error.

Comment: Can you tell us what `?? null` does?

Comment: this thing got me confused and i'm not sure i wrote it :/

Comment: Can you write the schema of your database and what classes are participate here - together with some description on "what it means" The best would be if you give minimal reproducibly example on exact place where you are facing issues. We don't know what kind of data is underneath

Comment: My question is update now. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You are creating a class object ParentResultDto.  There is a property.DepartmentLevel.  What is the type for DepartmentLevel?  You have are trying to set DepartmentLevel = ChildResultDto.  I think the two types are different.

Comment: ChildResultDto contains two field. Level(byte) and PersonnelCount (int)